# add_menu_page include a php page from theme directory

Tags: add-menu-page

I have added some custom tables to a wordpress and trying to add wp-admin section to manage them. By using following code I have successfully added a menu item in wp-admin but I'm unable to call the php page that resides into my theme folder

```
add_menu_page('Private Messages', 'Private Messages', 'manage_options',
              'message_admin', 'message-admin.php',
               get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/style/images/message.png');
```

in error_log it gives me this error

> PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'message-admin.php' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/idon.dev/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470, referer: http://idon.dev/wp-admin/admin.php?page=message_admin

**Update:**

The wordpress says

> $function
>
> (string) (optional) The function that displays the page content for
>   the menu page. Default: None. Technically, the function parameter is
>   optional, but if it is not supplied, then WordPress will assume that
>   including the PHP file will generate the administration screen,
>   without calling a function. **Most plugin authors choose to put the
>   page-generating code in a function within their main plugin file. In
>   the event that the function parameter is specified, it is possible to
>   use any string for the file parameter.** This allows usage of pages such
>   as ?page=my_super_plugin_page instead of
>   ?page=my-super-plugin/admin-options.php.

I know what does it mean

> PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function

but what I'm trying to achieve is to call a page rather of function. what is according to wordpress is possible, or guide me if I'm wrong.

Please note that I don't want to include page in functions, I will rather be happy to add my code into function.

Comment: try changing `'message-admin.php'` to the full path

Comment: nop. not working, in error_log after change it shows me this, that is correct path.. http://idon.dev/wp-content/themes/idon/message_admin.php

Comment: I said path not url!

Comment: still the same result..

Comment: Your `message-admin.php` argument should be a callback function, not a file. See [`add_menu_page` on the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page)

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you what the problem is...

> PHP Warning: `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a
>   **valid callback, function** ...

Your "callback" isn't a function. It is a file. It doesn't work that way. You will need a helper function to include a file. Something like:

```
add_menu_page(
  'Private Messages', 
  'Private Messages', 
  'manage_options',
  'message_admin', 
  'include_message_admin',
  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/style/images/message.png'
);

function include_message_admin() {
  // include('/path/to/message-admin.php');
  // something like
  include(get_template_directory().'/message-admin.php');
  // or 
  include(get_stylesheet_directory().'/message-admin.php');
}
```

Comment: please check the update in the question